# Crontab: Running a Single Command Inline

Tags: command, cron, restart

I want to run a single command from a crontab. Rather than create a bash file for just one command, is it possible to run a crontab somehow like this:

```
# Everyday at 3 am, restart the server.
0 3 * * * 'sudo shutdown -r now'
```

Instead of:

```
0 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/restart.bash
```

Can something like that be done?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can type the command in-line, but it must be typed the same as if you were on the command line. You do not type single quotes `'` on the command line, so you should not type them in the crontab either.

Finally, a command which requires root access must be run in the root crontab. (i.e. edit using `sudo crontab -e` instead of plain `crontab -e`, or log in as root using `su -` before typing `crontab -e`)

So in your example, you should type this in the crontab:

```
# Everyday at 3 am, restart the server.
0 3 * * * shutdown -r now
```

(sudo has no effect, removed single quotes)